# Showing No line when using linespoints in GNUPLOT

Tags: gnuplot

I am loading data from "forward_vs_node.dat" file where data are as follows:

```
70      0.8298  
80      0.8614  
90      0.8858  
100     0.9048  
110     0.9199  
120     0.9318  
130     0.9414  
140     0.9493  
150     0.9557  
160     0.9610  
170     0.9654  
180     0.9692  
190     0.9723  
200     0.9750
```

and I am using a .plt file where I write:

```
set term pdfcairo enhanced font "Times-New-Roman,10"
set     output "node_vs_reachability.pdf"                 
unset   label        
set     xlabel "Nodes in the network" font "Times-New-Roman,10"    
set     ylabel "Reachability" font "Times-New-Roman,10"  
set     x2label "Nodes vs Reachability" font "Times-New-Roman,10"
set     logscale y


set     xrange [70:200] 
set     yrange [0.7:1.0]    
set     xtics nomirror (70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200) 
        font "Times-New-Roman,10"
set     ytics nomirror (0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0) font "Times-New-Roman,10" 
set     size 1,1

set     style line  1 lt 1 lw 2 pt 3 ps 0.5
set     style line  2 lt 2 lw 1 pt 2
set     style line  3 lt 3 lw 1 pt 3
set     style line  4 lt 4 lw 1 pt 4
set     style line  5 lt 5 lw 1 pt 6
set     style line  6 lt 6 lw 1 pt 8
plot "forward_vs_node.dat" using 1:2 title 'Analytical Result' with `linespoints lt 1 lw 2 pt 3 ps 0.5
```

the points are showing but no lines are visible. Please help...

Comment: The most obvious observation is that you have a single quote before the `linespoints` keyword

Comment: ... which also gives an error message.

Comment: sorry that was just a typing mistake here...I didn't have this single quote in my original file.. I solve the problem of my missing lines. the .dat file was broken. thanks a lot everyone